# Como aplicar !important em uma propriedade com múltiplos valores

Tags: css, css3

Estou tendo algumas dificuldades com a precedência de seletores do CSS para criar um fundo dinâmico (transição de imagens.) na primeira seção/div apresentada no site. Atualmente tenho o seguinte cenário:

HTML:

```
        <section id="intro" class="intro main style1 dark fullscreen">
            <div class="content container small">
                <header>
                    <h2 class="shade"></h2>
                </header>
                <p class="shade">[TEXTO]</p>
                <footer>
                    <a href="#one" class="button style2 down">Mais</a>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
        ...
        <section id="intro4" class="intro main style1 dark fullscreen">
            <div class="content container small">
                <header>
                    <h2 class="shade"></h2>
                </header>
                <p class="shade">[TEXTO]</p>
                <footer>
                    <a href="#one" class="button style2 down">Mais</a>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
```

CSS: (o "ideal" seria, onde tenho propriedades específicas por ID e propriedades genéricas que se aplicam a todas, por classe.)

```
#intro {
    background: url('images/overlay.png'), url('../images/intro.jpg');
}
#intro2 {
    background: url('images/overlay.png'), url('../images/intro2.jpg');
}
#intro3 {
    background: url('images/overlay.png'), url('../images/intro3.jpg');
}
#intro4 {
    background: url('images/overlay.png'), url('../images/intro4.jpg');
}
.intro {
    background-size: 256px 256px, cover;
    background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
    background-position: top left, bottom center;
    background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

Para evitar repetição e fazer algo como:

```
#intro {
    background: url('images/overlay.png'), url('../images/intro.jpg');
    background-size: 256px 256px, cover;
    background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
    background-position: top left, bottom center;
    background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
}
...
#intro4 {
    background: url('images/overlay.png'), url('../images/intro4.jpg');
    background-size: 256px 256px, cover;
    background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
    background-position: top left, bottom center;
    background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

Pensei em recorrer a propriedade `!important`, que faria com que o seletor de classe (que normalmente seria sobreposto por `background-size: initial` e `background-attachment: initial`, já que ids terem precedência sobre classes.) não tivessem de ser repetidas, se aproximando de um conceito **DRY** (Don't Repeat Yourself) - Sugestões de como melhorar deixar "mais" DRY, são bem-vindas.

Já fiz isso em propriedades como `font-size: 200% !important` e claramente funcionou OK. No entanto, em seletores com mais de um valor, como o caso do `background-size` e `background-attachment`, o inspetor de propriedades (no meu caso, **Chrome** *Dev Tools*.) diz que a propriedade abaixo seria inválida:

```
background-attachment: fixed !important, fixed !important;
```

Enquanto que o seguinte:

```
background-attachment: fixed, fixed !important;
```

Não traz o resultado esperado.

Alguém poderia me dizer se:

(1) É possível acrescentar `!important` em uma propriedade *shorthand* com múltiplos valores
(2) Caso seja possível, como fazê-lo, observando as melhores práticas e
(3) Se existe outra maneira de alcançar o mesmo resultado, preservando a atual estrutura HTML (pois preciso de alguns modelos genéricos apenas **nessas** `<sections>`/`<divs>`, embora cada uma tenha seu próprio fundo com imagem.), qual seria e como implementar.

Comment: Estás a gerar esse código no servidor, ou é HTML/CSS já feito que tens de usar? Assim podias fazer algumas melhoras para ser mais DRY...

Comment: HTML/CSS manual. Sou adepto de SASS/SCSS mas no caso não estou compilando nada, nem Node.js ou algo do tipo. Busco ser DRY em tudo, pra evitar aquela macarronada de seletores e tags desnecessárias que ficam poluindo o código. E é justamente por não usar SASS neste projeto que estou tendo essa dificuldade - se estivesse, simplesmente faria um `@extend`, que teria o mesmo resultado em CSS que não desejo, mas seria mais fácil de manter e atualizar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que o correto seja:

```
background-attachment: fixed, fixed !important;
```

Apesar de não estar trazendo o resultado que você espera, essa regra na classe sobrepõe a regra definida para o ID. Apesar disso o ideal é evitar usar `!important`, pois deixa o código mais difícil de manter. Um link interessante sobre isso:

http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Acho que o maior problema no seu código é a regra do ID estar sobrescrevendo a regra da classe, já que você define regras para `background` em ambos. Não seria mais simples você transformar aqueles IDs em classes? Dessa forma você teria classes que definem regras mais genéricas e classes que definem regras mais específicas e isso soluciona o seu problema da precedência do ID, sem ter que usar o `!important`. Algo como:

HTML:

```
<section class="intro intro1">
...
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.intro1 {
  background: url('images/overlay.png'), url('../images/intro.jpg');
}
...
.intro {
  background-size: 256px 256px, cover;
  background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
  background-position: top left, bottom center;
  background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Essa era minha idéia, usar o ID apenas para o que serve especificamente para aquela seção. O que acontece é que, atualmente, faço algumas chamadas em jQuery mencionando o ID, sendo #intro a introdução de verdade, enquanto os #introX são placeholders pra trocar de fundo. Além do que já estou meio saturado de classes, mas pode ser essa a única alternativa a usar o `!important`. Estou ciente das nocividades de utilizar o `!important` e que seu uso deve ser consciente, pra não tornar o CSS um code-hell. Obrigado, vou considerar! :)